# Passing data to Google Chart API

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, google-visualization

Firstly, the Google Chart API example from Google (it is javascript) actually

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      // There is of coz some thing else but i just ignore them, just focus on the data here
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addRows([
          ['2004', 1000, 400],
          ['2005', 1170, 460],
          ['2006', 660, 1120],
          ['2007', 1030, 540]
        ]);
    </script>
```

Now i modify to become this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function drawChart(reading) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addRows([reading]);
    </script>
```

**(I implement in servlet)**
Now, i wish to pass my own data ( after reading from database) and make it to a string.  pass it to the modified javascript by calling drawChart(reading)

```
//After some action retrieving data from db and make it to a data string like this
        String reading = "['2011',1000,400],['2009',800,200]";
        out.println("<body onload=\"drawChart("+reading");\">");
            //drawing is here
            out.println("</body>");
```

**However, it seems that JS can't accept such string variable, what kind of format should i pass the variable to the JS? Or i shouldn't use String reading but others? But there isn't such kind of variable type in Java..**

Comment: you have a typo, it should be `"<body onload=\"drawChart(" + reading +");\">"`.. anyway i don't like how you pass the data to the drawChart =P but if you'll only have an array of two elements it's ok

Comment: ya just typo but just ignore it. i just wonder why it can't accept my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let Java print **exactly** the same data as you would write in plain vanilla JavaScript. You do not need to convert the data at all. Java doesn't execute JavaScript. Java just generates JavaScript code which get executed later when arrived at webbrowser.

```
String reading = "[['2004', 1000, 400],['2005', 1170, 460],['2006', 660, 1120],['2007', 1030, 540]]";
```

Comment: You need to be more specific in "it is not working". Start by reading the JS error console. Please note that you need to make sure that you have removed those incorrect `[]`s around `data.addRows([reading]);` so that it becomes correctly `data.addRows(reading);`. But that should be nothing more than obvious if you **understand** JS.

Comment: it's working now, the mistake is i should add one pair of [] to my reading and delete the [] in my modified js, thank you sir